# how can chinese words auto break in <Text> in react native?

Tags: react-native

from the example, I know the  will auto break the words, but when I try to put chinese into the  but it isn't break.

`return (
      <Text>
        中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行
      </Text>
    );`

Comment: The problem is unclear - I tried this and here's the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdjiorirwd8dc2a/Screenshot%202015-04-04%2012.17.44.png?dl=0 i.e. it wraps onto multiple lines.

Comment: can you tell me how it works?

Answer (score 1):

I literally just made an app like this:

```
var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行中文如何换行
      </Text>
    );
  }
});
```

And in the simulator it looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdjiorirwd8dc2a/Screenshot%202015-04-04%2012.17.44.png?dl=0

Comment: Please, if this is the correct answer then it is good etiquette for you to mark it as such... :)

Comment: but I solve this problem is I set the width of the View, I cannot confirm you answer is the correct answer.sorry

Comment: Fixed width? Or flex?